# Авторизация на Яндекс с помощью Python

Tags: python, requests, авторизация, веб-сайт

Нужно получить некоторые данные из аккаунта Яндекс с помощью скрипта (selenium и api не подойдет). Пробовал авторизироваться с помощью запросов, результат - страница авторизации без данных. Как можно решить данную проблему?

```
from requests import post
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

link = "https://passport.yandex.com/auth"
user = UserAgent().random

header = {
    'user-agent': user
}

data = {
    'login': 'login',
    'password': 'password',
}

response = post(link, data=data, headers=header).text
print(response)
```

Изменено:

Заметил, что при авторизации, после ввода логина идет перенаправление. Изменил код. Теперь все должно сохранятся (куки при перенаправлении), идет отправка нужных данных на каждую из страниц, так же научился генерировать process_uuid. Но все равно не работает. Сейчас так вообще "cannot post".

```
from requests import post, Session
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from uuid import uuid4

link = "https://passport.yandex.ru/auth"
link2 = "https://passport.yandex.ru/auth/welcome"
user = UserAgent().random
session = Session()

header = {
    'user-agent': user
}

data = {
    'login': 'login',
    'process_uuid': uuid4(),
}

data2 = {
    'password': 'password',
    'retpath': 'https://passport.yandex.ru/profile'
}

response = session.post(link, data=data, headers=header).text
response = session.post(link2, data=data2, headers=header).text

with open("auth.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(response)
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: https://yandex.ru/dev/passport/

Comment: @Jack_oS , API не вариант, вообще.

Comment: selenium не подойдет, api не вариант ;) только requests, только хардкор?

Comment: @Jack_oS , нужно чтобы при запуске скрипта выполнялись определенные действия, без открытия браузера или использования API. Конкретно мне нужно с помощью скрипта сделать регистрацию и получение токена для Яндекс диска. (все исключительно в благих целях)

Comment: @Jack_oS , так вы не знаете как можно решить проблему? Видел при авторизации передаются некоторые ключи, типа uuid и csrf. Они обязательны?

Comment: да, конечно обязательны... одним user-agent там не отделаешься... потом еще с капчей будете сражаться

Comment: @Jack_oS , ну капча у Яндекса не сложная, хорошо что просто картинки. В интернете есть примеры нейронок для их распознавания. Так что это не проблема. Меня интересует, пролучится ли авторизировать после передачи ключей? И как можно эти самые ключи сгенерировать?

Comment: @Jack_oS , и вообще, реально ли с помощью запросов реализовать регистрацию и получение токена?

Comment: @Jack_oS , кое-что изменил. Посмотрите вопрос. Может поможете.

Comment: c помощью библиотеки selenium легко, с обходом капчи даже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в неправильной отправке данных. Даже csrf token и uuid не понадобились.

```
from requests import post, Session
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

link = "https://passport.yandex.com/auth"
user = UserAgent().random

headers = {
'user-agent': user
}

data = {
'login': 'login',
'passwd': 'password',
}

session = Session()

responce = session.post(link, headers=headers, data=data)

with open("responce.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(responce.text)
```