# Верификация через yandex, не могу сделать. Впервые делаю. помогите решить(((((((((

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, аутентификация

> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smpt.yandex.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 456
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'моя почта@yandex.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD ='ключ'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
# EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

сигнал

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        print("send mail")
        connection = get_connection(
            host=settings.EMAIL_HOST,
            port=settings.EMAIL_PORT,
            username=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            password=settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD,
            use_tls=True
      )
        send_mail(
            'Subject here',
            'Here is the message.',
           settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
           [instance.email],
           fail_silently=False,
     )
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Answer (score -1):

Я хотел оставить комментарий, но не могу этого сделать
Советую посмотреть это: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1239229/Авторизация-на-Яндекс-с-помощью-python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1239229/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-python)
Вам обязательно понадобится:https://oauth.yandex.ru
Там нужно создать приложение. Токены скопировать и вставить в Ваш код.
Надеюсь, я смог Вам помочь.